# I have 2 if statement but only the first is executed what could be the wrong

Tags: php

I have 2 if statements but only the first is executed  what could the problem, Anyone see what is wrong here? will be appreciated

```
 if(!empty($firstfile)){

     // do the insert and give success message
    $data = $this->mymodal->addmy();

    if($data == TRUE){

     echo "data inserted";
    }else{
     echo "data not inserted"
    }

}else{
    // do the insert with placeholder and give success message
     $data = $this->mymodal->addmy();

     if($data == TRUE){

     echo "data inserted";
    }else{
     echo "data not inserted"
    }
}// end of the first file


 if(!empty($secondfile)){

     // do the insert and give success message
    $data = $this->mymodal->addmy();

    if($data == TRUE){

     echo "data inserted";
    }else{
     echo "data not inserted"
    }

}else{
    // do the insert with placeholder and give success message
     $data = $this->mymodal->addmy();

     if($data == TRUE){

     echo "data inserted";
    }else{
     echo "data not inserted"
    }
}// end of the second file
```

Comment: try `if(!empty($secondfile)){echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You're in !')</script>";}`. Do you get the echo ? If you don't have it the problem is because `$secondfile` is empty

Comment: I have tried to echo in the second file it is successfully reach there.

Comment: Fine, so `$secondfile` isn't empty. How you know the second one isn't executed ? It echoes nothing ?

Comment: if $secondfile is empty it is echoes too

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code. I asked you what error/problem do you get ? How do you know the second statment doesn't execute ?

Comment: I have an image url to insert into the database using the variable $data function but it does not insert while both if statement are using the same function in my modal

Comment: The first if statement is executed but the second does not, that is why i am suspecting the if statements

Comment: I don't understand. Everything works except the url insertion ? If your program can echo everything  the problem in your inserting. Put a echo before your inserting to see if the program reaches there

Comment: Ok, Thank you Ram, Let me try to check my insert function clearly.

Comment: put `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You're in !')</script>";` right before (or after) your query. If it shows the alert, then your query doesn't work otherwise the problem is that your program doesn't reach there

Comment: Keep Me Informed  ;)

Comment: I have placed the alert in the second if statement just after my insert function it does not alert

Comment: So, the problem is that your program doesn't reach that if, so it doesn't reach the inserting statment. Here is your problem . Try to put the alert before the query to test but I think it won't echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! i finally find the answer, i tried to advance the second if statement right after the first if statement return true. That means if you have third if statement put it after the second if statement return true and so on....

```
if(!empty($firstfile)){

     // do the insert and give success message
$data = $this->mymodal->addmy();

if($data == TRUE){

 //echo "data inserted";


if(!empty($secondfile)){

 // do the insert and give success message
$data = $this->mymodal->addmy();

if($data == TRUE){

 echo "data inserted";
}else{
 echo "data not inserted"
}

}else{
// do the insert with placeholder and give success message
 $data = $this->mymodal->addmy();

 if($data == TRUE){

 echo "data inserted";
}else{
 echo "data not inserted"
}
}// end of second


}else{
 echo "data not inserted"
}

}else{
// do the insert with placeholder and give success message
 $data = $this->mymodal->addmy();

 if($data == TRUE){

 echo "data inserted";



}else{
 echo "data not inserted"
}
```

}// end of the first file